# float vs double (in Java)

Tags: java, floating-point-precision

Is there ever a case where these two methods would return different values given the same inputs?

```
int compare1(float a, float b)
{
    return Double.compare(a, b);
}

int compare2(float a, float b)
{
    return Float.compare(a, b);
}
```

By the same token, is it true (or false) that any number storable in a java's Float can be stored in a java's Double without losing any precision?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>Yes; casting doubles to floats can yield different results.</strike>

If the difference between `a` and `b` is too small to show up in a float, `compare2()` will return `0` whereas `compare1()` would not.

---

You just edited the question to reverse what you were asking.  The new answer is:

I'm almost certain that they will always be the same.

Comment: What about my question about Float being a subset of Double?

Comment: @user1508893: I'm reasonably certain that it is, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Actually, I made some mistake in the question. Just updated it. Sorry!

Answer (score 4):

[Every `float` can be represented exactly as a `double`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/259514/367273) From this it follows that the two functions always return the same result.

Answer (score 1):

A `double` just gives you more bits of precision beyond the decimal place than the `float`. If all those those extra bits are zero then you have the same value as the float. So yes, all `float`s can be converted to `double`s without losing precision.

Comment: It also gives you a maximum exponent of 1023 as against 127.